# The innerText in tbody is not printing

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, export-to-excel

The "thead" is giving all the data in side by innerText, but "tbody" is blank. No "tr" and even "td" is helping.

```
Sub ScrapeOddsUsingXMLHTTP11()
Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTable1, HTMLTable2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

XMLRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=MCX", False
XMLRequest.send

If XMLRequest.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox XMLRequest.Status & " - " & XMLRequest.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLRequest.responseText

Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("priceInfoTable")
Set HTMLTable1 = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("thead")(0)
Set HTMLTable2 = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)

Debug.Print HTMLTable1.innerText
Debug.Print HTMLTable2.innerText

End Sub
```

Please help me there the image is incerted.[image]

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: its printing spaces.

Comment: Can you try the below answer ?

Comment: After the `HTTP` `GET` request, the `TBODY` is empty. In a browser it then gets filled using `JavaScript` (`AJAX`). But that runs after the `HTTP` `GET` request and needs a browser or somewhat else which is able running `JavaScript`.

Comment: The data you want comes dynamically from a different endpoint. This API call `https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=MCX` returning json.

Comment: CAN WE USE IT.?